# Count of distinct duplicated characters in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates

I've written code to find the amount of duplicated characters in a string input. However after reading the specification, I realise this isn't what is being asked. Yes, I need to count the duplicated characters, but not the amount of that particular character, I need the amount of all characters being duplicated.

I've given an input and output to help explain better. I don't think I'm doing a good job.

Input: 
"abcdea" => "a" is duplicated =>
Output:
1

Input:
"abcdeae" => "a" and "e" is duplicated =>
Output:
2

Input:
"abcdeaed" => "a", "d" and "e" is duplicated =>
Output:
3

I've put my code below. Can anyone help adjust my code please?

```
public static int duplicatesCount(String text) 
    {
        Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
        char[] carray = text.toCharArray();
        for (char c : carray)
        {
            if (map.containsKey(c))
            {
                map.put(c, map.get(c) +1);
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
        Set <Character> setChar = map.keySet();
        int returnC = 1;
        for (Character c : setChar)
        {
            if (map.get(c) > 1)
            {
                returnC = map.get(c);
            }
        }
        return returnC;
```

Comment: `returnC` currently corresponds to number of occurrences of the last letter that occurs more than once. Instead of overwriting `returnC` each time, add to it (but first initialize it at `0` instead of `1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach - without using `Map` or sorting algorithm.

```
public static int duplicatesCount(String text) {
    int cnt = 0;
    while (text.length() > 1) {
        char firstLetter = text.charAt(0);
        if (text.lastIndexOf(firstLetter) > 0) {
            cnt++;
            text = text.replaceAll(("" + firstLetter), "");
        } else {
            text = text.substring(1, text.length());
        }
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

The basic idea is to go through a string, char-by-char and check does the character exist somewhere in the string ( `if (text.lastIndexOf(firstLetter) > 0)`). If it exists increment `cnt` and then remove all occurrences of the character in the string.
Otherwise, just remove the fist character (`text = text.substring(1, text.length());`)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance :) I ended up not using HashMaps at all. It was causing the IDE to time out when I ran it. Thank you again :)

Comment: No problem. "It was causing the IDE to time out when I ran it." - perhaps you have an infinitive loop. Check the code again.

Comment: If you find some of these answers helpful and useful for your solution you should vote up or/and accept the solution.

Comment: I did vote for your solution but because my reputation is under 15 a pop up said my vote wouldn't be displayed. 
Not sure how to select a solution ..

Comment: I didn't mean just in my answer, but generally: Any answer that helps you. Also, if you accept the solution you will get reputation up.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do this is to sort the string and then iterate through it.  If the previous character = the current character, you increase the duplicate number and don't increment it again util you see the character change.

This requires no extra storage (e.g. the hash map).

This can also be used to count the number of duplicates of each letter with a minor change :).

Answer (score 1):

Just count everytime you come across a character that has a value greater than 1 in your hashmap

```
int returnC = 0;
for (Character c : setChar)
{
    if (map.get(c) > 1)
        returnC++;
}
```

Or you can do it while you're creating your hashmap like this

```
Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
char[] carray = text.toCharArray();
Set <Character> setChar = new Set<Character>(); //initialize the set up here
for (char c : carray)
{
    if (map.containsKey(c))
    {
        map.put(c, map.get(c) +1);
        setChar.add(c); //just add to set when a char already exists
    }
    else
    {
        map.put(c, 1);
    }
}

return setChar.size(); //then simply return the size of the set
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your snippet...

```
int returnC = 0;
for (Character c : setChar)
    {
        if (map.get(c) > 1)
        {
            returnC ++;  //for each which has more than one instance
        }
    }
    return returnC;
```

Comment: yep! Forgot to alter when pasting

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String` methods

```
int count = 0;
String s = "abcdeabc";
while(s.length() > 0) {
    String c = s.substring(0, 1);
    if(s.lastIndexOf(c) != 0) {
        count++;
    }
    s = s.replaceAll(c, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code you are returning the value not the count.

For Eg:

1. If your input was "abcdea", then returnC holds the value 2 which is the
   number of times the key a has repeated.
2. If your input was "abcdabeb" where a is repeated twice and b is repeated
   thrice. Your output will be 3, as returnC will be holding the value for the key
   b.

You can modify your code like this.

```
 Set <Character> setChar = map.keySet();
 int returnC = 0;
 for (Character c : setChar) {
       if (map.get(c) > 1) { 
             returnC++;
       } 
 }
 return returnC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also we can user String Buffer class to to create another string of duplicate charracters-- and then we can display it--

```
public static void main(String arghya[])
{
    String name="ARGHYA MUKHERJEE";
    StringBuffer duplicate=new StringBuffer();

    Set<Character> charlist=new HashSet<Character>();

    for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++) {
        Character c=name.charAt(i);
        if(charlist.contains(c))
        { 
            duplicate.append(c);
            //System.out.println(c+ " is repeatitive character in the string");
        }
        else {
            charlist.add(c);
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Duplicate characters which has appeared are as follows: "+duplicate);     
}
```